# Excel to PDF with a watermark if user selects VBNo

Tags: excel, pdf, watermark, vba

All,

I have the below code which exports excel sheets into PDF format. I would like to know if it is possible to generate a watermark which says "DRAFT" on the PDF if the user selects "VBNo"?

*Please note this is only a snippet of the module.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
 strPath = strPath & "\"
 strFileName = strFileName & ".pdf"


 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
 Type:=xlTypePDF, _
 filename:=strPath & strFileName, _
 IgnorePrintAreas:=False
```

Comment: It seems like there's been a lot of PDF/VBA questions lately, and the answer is the similar for all: it's possible (albeit complicated) but requires licensed Adobe software, such as **Adobe Acrobat ***(not reader)* or **Adobe Distiller**.   Even then, Adobe's API's technically only support C++ or Javascript, but with enough Googling you can find some help, like [this](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?39616-Add-Background-to-PDF-using-Excel-VBA) and [this](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/adding-watermark-pdf.html)...  You might be better off to re-think your plan. *Good luck!*

Comment: Other way is to write a VBA code that would add watermark to sheets before exporting to PDF (example: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-a-watermark-in-excel-a372182a-d733-484e-825c-18ddf3edf009) and remove it after export.

Comment: @tomjohnriddle +1. I was literally writing that comment for the past 10m whilst getting distracted doing other stuff. To note, it won't be a watermark as such, more of a background image. But this would be the easiest and simplest solution.